# Comparing with a Blacklist and saving the output

Tags: perl, bash

I have 2 text files, the source list, and a "black list", which it'll compare against the source list (case insensitive) and if any lines is detected with any of the blacklist lines, make a "3rd list" (output) of the offending items and line numbers (of the source file).

Source List Example:

```
*cat
##dog
.pig
$qwer
|cup|
*coke*
^clock^
```

Comment: What have you tried? Which parts are causing you problems? We're not going to write the entire program for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
grep -Finf blklst srclst
```

Comment: looks good!, though doing exact matches.. so if the blacklist has "dog" and source has dog20, it would ignore it (because its not the same)

Comment: @user: If your blacklist doesn't have any regex characters such as `[`, `*` or `.`, etc., You can leave off the `-F` and it will do partial matches.